# Setting adapter from main activity to its fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Disclaimer: i'm a noob

The scenario here is that i have a main activity acting as the mediator for my three fragments and within the three fragments has their own respective recycler views.

my problem here is that i need to set all of the recycler views's adapters of three frags in the main, it can't be done by intent/bundle since they're all simultaneously running and i can't seem to call the recycler views of 3 frags from the main activity.

**Main example**

```
public class classList_index extends AppCompatActivity {

private float c_qGrade;
private List<QuarterlyGrade_Config> TransGrade;
private List<tracksettingEquiv_Config> equiv;
private List<maxGrade_Config> maxgrade;
private List<batchList_config> studentList;

f_ww_Adapter wwAdapter;
f_pt_Adapter ptAdapter;
f_qe_Adapter qeAdapter;

FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_class_list_index);

    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    populateList();
}

private void populateList()
{
    studentList = new ArrayList<>();


    final String loadURL = APP.DOMAIN+"/selectStudents.php";
    RequestQueue reqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(classList_index.this);

    StringRequest loadRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, loadURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){
            try
            {
                JSONObject CLASS_LIST_JSON = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray STUDENT_LIST_JARRAY = CLASS_LIST_JSON.getJSONArray("student_list");

                for(int students = 0; students < STUDENT_LIST_JARRAY.length(); students++)
                {
                    JSONObject p_JSONObject = STUDENT_LIST_JARRAY.getJSONObject(students);

                    final String p_studentID    = p_JSONObject.getString("USERID");
                    final String p_lastName  = p_JSONObject.getString("LASTNAME");
                    final String p_firstName  = p_JSONObject.getString("FIRSTNAME");
                    final String p_middleName  = p_JSONObject.getString("MIDDLENAME");
                    final String p_gender  = p_JSONObject.getString("GENDER");
                    final String p_ww1  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW1");
                    final String p_ww2  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW2");
                    final String p_ww3  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW3");
                    final String p_ww4  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW4");
                    final String p_ww5  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW5");
                    final String p_ww6  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW6");
                    final String p_ww7  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW7");
                    final String p_ww8  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW8");
                    final String p_ww9  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW9");
                    final String p_ww10  = p_JSONObject.getString("WW10");
                    final String p_pt1  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT1");
                    final String p_pt2  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT2");
                    final String p_pt3  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT3");
                    final String p_pt4  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT4");
                    final String p_pt5  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT5");
                    final String p_pt6  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT6");
                    final String p_pt7  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT7");
                    final String p_pt8  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT8");
                    final String p_pt9  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT9");
                    final String p_pt10  = p_JSONObject.getString("PT10");
                    final String p_qe  = p_JSONObject.getString("QE1");

                    batchList_config studentConfig = new batchList_config(p_studentID,p_firstName,p_lastName,p_middleName,p_gender,p_ww1,p_ww2,p_ww3,p_ww4,p_ww5,p_ww6,p_ww7,p_ww8,p_ww9,p_ww10,p_pt1,p_pt2,p_pt3,p_pt4,p_pt5,p_pt6,p_pt7,p_pt8,p_pt9,p_pt10,p_qe);
                    studentList.add(studentConfig);
                }
                wwAdapter = new f_ww_Adapter(classList_index.this, studentList);
                ptAdapter = new f_pt_Adapter(classList_index.this, studentList);
                qeAdapter = new f_qe_Adapter(classList_index.this, studentList);


                //where the adapter of recycler views should all be set 
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                volleyErrorClass.catchInvalidResponse(e.toString(), classList_index.this);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            volleyErrorClass.catchError(error, classList_index.this);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    reqQueue.add(loadRequest);

}

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: 
                return f_wworks.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return f_ptasks.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return f_qexams.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Written\nWorks";
            case 1:
                return "Performance\nTasks";
            case 2:
                return "Quarterly\nAssessment";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**Fragment example**

```
public class f_wworks extends Fragment {

private static RecyclerView rv_ww;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public f_wworks() {
}

public static f_wworks newInstance() {
    f_wworks fragment = new f_wworks();

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View holder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wworks, container, false);

    rv_ww = (RecyclerView) holder.findViewById(R.id.rv_wworks);
    rv_ww.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    rv_ww.setHasFixedSize(true);



    return holder;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    //} else {
      //  throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
        //        + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using instance of `fragment` in `Main` and using it to call a public method in `Fragment` as in

**Main**

```
//declare globally

    f_wworks fw;
    f_ptasks fp;
    f_qexams fq;

     @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: 
                    fw = f_wworks.newInstance();
                    return fw;
                case 1:
                    fp = f_ptasks.newInstance();
                    return fp;
                case 2:
                    fq = f_qexams.newInstance();
                    return  fq;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

private void populateList()
{
//Once you created adapter
   fw.setDataToAdapter(wwAdapter); //do this to other fragments
}
```

Now in you fragment

**f_wworks**

```
public class f_wworks extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView rv_ww;

public void setDataToAdapter(f_ww_Adapter fwa){
   rv_ww.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager());
   rv_ww.setAdapter(fwa);
}

//all other stuff
}
```

Comment: ohhh it's simple and easy to understand, thanks!

though, 
error points out and said: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void maximum.beta_v4_classrecord.f_qexams.setDataToAdapter(maximum.beta_v4_classrecord.f_qe_Adapter)' on a null object reference
and it's pointing to the fw.setDataToAdapter(wwAdapter);

Comment: Yes because, it will only create instance for first two `fragments`, when you swipe to third ,then it will create for third one, so remove `f_qexams.setDataToAdapter()` and put it in page change listener of `view pager`

Comment: what do you mean? is it because of the `default: return null;` on the `switch` when selecting a fragment? do i need to put all the `.setDataToAdapter()` within the **page change listener** of `ViewPager`?

Comment: Because it will only call getitem with positions 0 and 1 at first and it won’t call getitem(2) unless swiped

Comment: >so remove `f_qexams.setDataToAdapter()` and put it in page change listener of `view pager`< , care to explain it further? i can't seem to grasp the entirety of your statement.